# Facebook - how to set the url of the application that post something to facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have an iOS Facebook application.

When a user posts something from the application to Facebook, the post looks great but the "signature" is not right like I wanted to be.

For example the signature for my application is "30 minutes ago via MYSUPERAPP"

And the MYSUPERAPP (my application) has the url  www.facebook.com/apps/........

The result I want is to have a MY URL, like www.mysuperapp.com
Same way as foursquare does it. (look at the attachment)

What do I have to change to make that happens?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the Site URL in your app settings. Do not set the canvas URL. And do not set the Page Tab URL.

Comment: Great, thanks.   I think I also needed the sign in permission to be publish_stream, and the post me/feeds.   That was the only way we could get it to work the way we want it.